# USB transfer speed between tablets and laptop

Tags: android, usb, adb, data-transfer

I'd like to install some "apk" to my android devices, using command like

`adb -s device install foo.apk`

I plugged 4 devices to my laptop. And installed apks to all of them at the same time.

I used a 4 port usb-hub (without power supply).

I am wondering if these concurrent installation/copying slow down the speed, compared to only plug one android device.

The current speed is like 1MB/s. The devices are nexus 7. The laptop is Macbook Pro.

Answer (score 0):

if your using a USB hub from you Mac it will slow down but not by much. Its because you will be using more bandwidth of the USB XHCI Host Controller. So the devices needs to split speeds to how ever many locations you are copying to and files copying concurrently. Also the CPU needs to work slightly harder therefore slowing down other processes.

However on ADB the difference is negligible. You will not be able to tell
I'm pretty sure this is the case anyways